# Segmentation fault with typecast

Tags: c, memory

When I run the following code it gives a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {  
  int i;  
  char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};  
  int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  
  unsigned int hacky_nonpointer;  
  hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;  
  for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // Iterate through the int array with the int_pointer.  
    printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n",  
    hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));  
    hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);  
  }  
  hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) int_array;  
  for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // Iterate through the int array with the int_pointer.  
    printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n",
    hacky_nonpointer, *((int *) hacky_nonpointer));  
    hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);  
  }  
}
```

I was actually trying to do a typecast example.  How can I resolve the segmentation fault?

Comment: This code is impossible to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My *guess* is that you're on a 64-bit machine, where pointers are 64 bits. That will lead to big problems (and [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) when you do

```
hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;
```

as the type `int` is typically still only 32 bits.

Once you're experimented with this, then throw it all away, and forget all about as well! This is bad code doing bad things that no real program should ever do.

Comment: OP's compiler should have warned about the pointer / integer size mismatch.

Comment: For the record, the safe way to store a pointer in an integral type is `uintptr_t hacky_nonpointer = (uintptr_t)(void*)p;`.  However, as the dude says, play around with this as a learning exercise, then throw it away.  You will never, ever want to write code anything like this in the real world.

Comment: @dbush If a compiler doesn’t warn about the conversion, the OP should turn on more warnings.  On gcc or clang, I usually compile with `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion`.

Comment: clang also has `-Weverything`, whence you can just turn off the ones you don't like (and I can all but promise there will be some).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Some_programmer_dude’s answer a bit, the safe way to store a pointer in an integral type is

```
#include <stdint.h>
/* ... */
uintptr_t hacky_nonpointer = (uintptr_t)(void*)p;
```

To convert back,

```
const char c = *(char*)(void*)hacky_nonpointer;
```

On most real-world compilers, a direct cast from any pointer type to `uintptr_t` will work just fine.  However, the standard technically only says that any pointer can be converted to `void*` and back, and that any `void*` can be converted to `uintptr_t` and back.

A round-trip conversion will get you an equivalent pointer back.  (See the footnote for if you care about the language-lawyering details.)  That is, you can convert `p` to a `uintptr_t` value and back, and you are guaranteed to get another pointer to the same object.  You cannot safely increment the `uintptr_t` value and convert that back, but you could increment the pointer and convert the incremented pointer to `uintptr_t` and back.  That is how you would safely do what you appear to want.

Converting to an integral type and adding 1 (or equivalently `sizeof(char)`, which is guaranteed to be 1) is not guaranteed to give you anything meaningful.  It’s possible to imagine esoteric implementations that will crash if you try to convert that value back to a pointer!  However, on mainstream compilers, it will work.

If your compiler didn’t give you a warning about this code, you need to turn on more warnings.  If it did, you shouldn’t ignore compiler warnings.

As the Dude said, though, you should never write code like that in the real world.  No program should ever do anything like that or will ever need to.

#### Footnote

There is one extremely pedantic loophole to this: the Standard guarantees that a pointer converted to `uintptr_t` and back will compare equal to the original pointer, and it forbids two pointers to compare equal unless they can be used the same way.  With one exception.

A pointer to the start of an array object might compare equal to a pointer one-past-the-end of a different array object.  By my reading of the standard, an implementation that allowed a pointer resulting from a round-trip conversion of either kind of pointer (the beginning of an array object, or one past its end) to be used in only one of those ways could claim to be technically in compliance.

However, any real-world implementation would allow such a pointer to be used in both contexts.  That the standard does not spell this out appears to be an oversight.

Comment: *"You could also increment ++p, do a round-trip conversion, and be guaranteed to get the same incremented pointer."* This claim is utterly not based on the standard.

Comment: Please also [see what GCC has to say about the use of uintptr_t](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala In case I wasn’t clear, you could write `char * q = ++p; uintptr_t x = (uintptr_t)(void*)q;` and then convert back `(char*)(void*)x` to get a pointer that compares equal to the incremented p. Incrementing the `uintptr_t` and converting that back is, indeed, a bug. (Which happens to work on certain implementations.)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I’ve rewritten the line of my post that appears to have led to the misunderstanding. We agree.